# Why compiler allows send a reference to iterator in function which takes a reference to const iterator?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, const-iterator

I am a little messed up with const_iterators. For example, let's consider the function:

```
void functionForConstIterator(std::list<int> const& list, std::list<int>::const_iterator& const_iter)
{
    const_iter = list.begin();
}
```

Now I can write:

```
void main()
{
    std::list<int> myList = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::list<int> const& listRef = myList;
    std::list<int>::iterator iter;

    functionForConstIterator(listRef, iter);
    *iter = 7;

    for (auto it = myList.begin(); it != myList.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << *it << " ";
}
```

The output is {7, 2, 3, 4, 5}. Why? If I get a const reference on a container, I have not to change it. This is Visual Studio 2015 compiler.

Comment: If a function parameter is a const reference, that just means the function can't change it. It won't make it starting being const outside the function.

Comment: [Your code is bogus](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1bc62e737a7e80f4)

Comment: But it is mean that if I have only const reference, not the container itself, I always can change it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ He specified that he is using the VS2015 compiler which means your link isn't valid since it shows that GCC correctly detects this as problematic. I suspect that the question warrants a VS2015 tag.

Comment: @nonsensickle [Wow, vs2015 actually allows to write such stuff without even a warning](http://rextester.com/RZMP77813)

Comment: Don't use "void main", use "int main" always.

Comment: @Sebastian Red Ok :)

Comment: Consider passing and returning iterators by value. Until msvc implementation is fixed (or not), this will save you from possible bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft STL's `list::iterator` derives from `list::const_iterator`. This is why you can pass a reference to your `iterator` to the function expecting a `const_iterator` without problems.

The assignment inside the function is thus a slicing assignment, but this has no particular effect in this case, since `iterator` has no virtual functions and introduces no new members.

Thus you have stealthily converted a `const_iterator` to an `iterator` thanks to the assignment.

**Edit:** I have created a Connect issue for this:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2962643

Comment: Is such implementation prohibited by the standard?

Comment: I don't think it technically is, since the standard specifies "this may not compile" only in very few places of the library, but it certainly is very poor quality of implementation.

Answer (score 2):

> If I get a const reference on a container, I should not be able to change it.

That's right. However, you are not getting a const reference on a container. despite its name, `const_iterator` is *not* a `const` from the point of view of the language. The name `const` is to indicate to programmers that you are not going to be able to change the container through this iterator. The iterator itself remains a fair target to be changed.

Moreover, the iterator is a `const_iterator` only inside the function. Outside the function, i.e. in `main`, it is a regular `std::list<int>::iterator`, which remains fully changeable before and after the call to the function.

Comment: But it's follow that if I have only const reference, not the container itself, I always can change the container. What's sense of const references in this case?

Comment: The real question is: should you be allowed to, directly or indirectly, assign a const iterator to a non-const iterator and in that way modify the underlying container. And the answer, IMO, should be **no**.

Comment: To clarify my statement further, changing a `const_iterator` to a straight `iterator` should not be allowed to be performed implicitly or indirectly .

Comment: @AnyaMitrushchienkova `const`-ness is associated with the thing that you declare for greater flexibility. You pick and choose what you want to be constant, in many combinations. You can make a const container, in which case the compiler is not going to let you make non-constant iterators from it. You can also make a `const` *regular* iterator, in which case the compiler is not going to let you modify the iterator itself, but it would let you modify the container. You can make a non-`const` *constant* iterator, in which case you would be able to modify the iterator, but not the container.